# MySQL php - adding three datas and order by

Tags: php, mysql

OK so let's say I have three fields called "mines, explodes, and tags" in a table. I want to add those three together and say they are the "kills" added up from the 3 fields and order them from highest to lowest (DESC). Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that will work! (But it won't be efficient.)

```
SELECT *, mines + explodes + tags AS kills
FROM your_table
ORDER BY kills DESC
```

If performance is a concern you should store the total as a column in the table and add an index to that column so that order by can use this index.

Comment: Hmm.. it takes a long time to load the page :| .. many queries?

Comment: try MySQL EXPLAIN command which helps you see what slows it down. If read speed is important, add the kills column and add index to it.